# Access control of mongodb via ansible not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, ansible

I have used `security.authorization: enabled` in mongod.conf but authentication check not performed. Now unauthorized users able to access db. I have to block such connections. Here I added my ansible playbook code

```
    - name: build mongodb image
      docker_image:
        name: mongodb:v1.0
    - name: Run mongodb-container
      docker_container:
        name: mongodb-container
        image: mongodb-image:v1.0
        volumes:
          - /db/:/data/db"
          - /mongodb/entryScript/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
        networks_cli_compatible: yes
        networks:
          - name: custom-network
        ports:
          - "20200:27017"
        restart: yes
    - name: Install pymongo
      pip:
        name: pymongo
        state: present
    - name: Add user
      mongodb_user:
        database: customDb
        name: user123
        password: xxxxxx
        login_host: localhost
        login_port: 20200
        login_user: admin_user
        login_password: xxxxxx
        state: present
    - name: Set config
      template:
        src: /templates/mongodb.yml
        dest: /etc/mongod.conf
        restart: yes
```

mongodb.yml having

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Comment: When you enable authentication then you need to create at least one admin user (i.e. user with `userAdmin` or `userAdminAnyDatabase` role). Did you create this? I am not sure, but I think the admin user must be created in `admin` database.

Comment: yeah already created via entry script. Actually no issue with adding user. issue only with --auth.

Comment: What do you mean by "can access admin db"? I guess some access is needed in any case, e.g. for interrogate your own privileges.

Comment: Sorry just typo, now corrected

Comment: Again, what do you mean? In MongoDB everybody can connect to the DB, however apart from commands like `db.help()` or `db.getMongo()`, etc. no command is permitted to be executed.

Comment: suppose we have database x and only allow assigned user to access x. This can be achieve in mongod using --auth or in config we can use authorization: enabled. But here not worked. I hope u got what in my mind.

Comment: No still not clear. Check credentials of this user with `db.getUser("<username>", { showPrivileges: true})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a lot found some solution. Before getting into code always remember 
*Start mongodb without access control and insert admin user. Then start mongodb with access control to perform authentication and insert remaining users using admin user details.*
 Instead of `security.authorization`,  `--auth` worked perfectly. Here i inserted admin user through entrypioint script.

/mongodb/entryScript/enrtypoint.js

```
db.createUser({
      user: "admin_user",
      pwd: "admin_pass",
      roles: [{ role: "root", db: "admin" }],
    });
```

Ansible playbook as follow

```
- name: build mongodb image
      docker_image:
        name: mongodb:v1.0
    - name: Run mongodb-container
      docker_container:
        name: mongodb-container
        image: mongodb-image:v1.0
        env:
         MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
        volumes:
          - /db/:/data/db"
          - /mongodb/entryScript/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
        ports:
          - "20200:27017"
        restart: yes
    - name: Install pymongo
      pip:
        name: pymongo
        state: present
    - name: Run mongodb-container with auth
      docker_container:
        name: mongodb-container
        command: "--auth"
        volumes:
          - /db/:/data/db
        networks_cli_compatible: yes
        networks:
          - name: custom-network
        ports:
          - "20200:27017"
        restart: yes
    - name: Add user
      mongodb_user:
        database: customDb
        name: user123
        password: xxxxxx
        login_host: localhost
        login_port: 20200
        login_user: admin_user
        login_password: admin_pass
        state: present
```